# Base64 encoding RFC2045 cannot decode image

Tags: xml, encoding, base64, decoding

I have been working with an image that I need to decode. It is an image encoded in base64binary. I cant really find out why it does not decode, maybe someone sees something that I don't? I tried various tools, formats but still no luck.

It comes encoded in base64binary from an XML Soap query.

I am adding the base64 here: https://dumpz.org/a5C5CNGyFGth

Comment: Your input is a base 64 string.  Not sure what it contains, but it is not an image.  Images normally have a ascii header and you string is missing the header.  I used following code :  byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
            string output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

Comment: Could it be that it is missing just the header, jdweng? Thank you so much for the quick answer. Maybe the header is hardcoded somewhere else. This string goes to a win32 app that shows it as an image. Do you think there is a chance to add the header?

Comment: All image formats I'm aware of have a header that specifies the image size and a few other image parameters. This usually leads to several bytes with low values. Your data however looks completely random. Could it be encrypted or obfuscated?

Comment: I think it could be that the header is cut off somehow and the application that gets this encoded string adds the header to it. But it definitely could be encrypted even more as it is a picture of a catalog that I want to crawl.

Comment: The number of bytes is really too small for an image.